# How to run a series of bash commands via Python?

Tags: python, bash, operating-system

Running on Windows system, I run bash.exe using subprocess.call().
Following is the code

```
def predict():
    os.system('notepad cmnd.txt')
    subprocess.call(['C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe'])
    print(file_contents)
    label = Label(master, text=file_contents)
    #subprocess.call(['c:/users/hp/open.py'])
    label.pack()
```

The handle passes to bash,thus not executing a couple of commands.
cd commands that runs on actually entering values return Missing Directory error.
ls command returns 'cannot run binary file' error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want here, but if you want to run bash commands in a Windows enviorment, you can try using [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
from subprocess import check_output

bash_commands = ['ls', 'pwd']

for command in bash_commands:
    output = check_output(['bash', '-c', command]).decode()
    print(output)
```

Which in this example, lists all files in the current directory and prints out the parent working directory.

Comment: Thank you.
I understand I was a bit unclear as I had been working on this for a while and have lost track of the wheres and what myself. :(
Let me give this a try,

Comment: @AbhinavSrivastav No problem. This example is probably too simplistic for what you want to do, but it should give a general idea.